# webpack gives me error at my config file at the plugins part saying that "plugins: [ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'"

Tags: webpack

[image]

project link:[project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dhxegg3b0xt23qf/AACpezu1pMqL6-JJDZfjg2fSa?dl=0)

in my config files I used:

```
 const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'Client'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    stats: 'verbose',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
                }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Simulate the removal of files
            dry: true,
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: true,
            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
            protectWebpackAssets: false
        })
    ]
}
```

////

```
    const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/index.js",
    mode: 'production',
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'Client'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test:  /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
                use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      name: '[name].[ext]',
                      outputPath: 'fonts/'
                    }
            }    
        ]
    },     
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: '[name].css'}),
        new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW()


    ]
    }
```

I am trying to add a loader to load font-awesome fonts
also at my config files:prod and dev there seems to be wrong brackets, I failed to know why the editor keeps telling me my brackets are wrong
and webpack is telling me there is error at the plugins line(36)

any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be enough to look at the webpack code, you use vscode which exactly shows where the error is.
`]` Is missing from plugins and the same applies to closing module.exports `}` at the end
And an example of how on github and not on the dropbox because in a moment you will turn off the dropbox and the point is that the code stays for others.

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const WorkboxPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'Client'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: '/\.js$/',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/'
          }
        }]
      },
    ], // it was missing
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
        filename: "./index.html",
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css'
      }),
      new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW()
    ]
  }
} // it was missing
```